# Iterate of Content Control text in Python docx in Document order

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

Edit: Sample file with content control [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13_bRvFsX5ZjHmTrqImFG7KdDIzCS04Eu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111601000534087705106&rtpof=true&sd=true) and output from my BilingualText Function [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gqRqorynjlD6CFVigDqAuGnOYaqfIsQD/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=111601000534087705106&rtpof=true&sd=true)

So I'm building a python Script that will iterate over all the Paragraphs in a Word Doc and convert to a bilingual format, such that this:

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Becomes this:

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| Paragraph 1 | Paragraph 1 |
| Paragraph 2 | Paragraph 2 |

I built the below function to accomplish this using `Python-docx`:

```py
def BilingualText(Doc: Document, SourceRight: bool) -> None:
"""Loops through all paragraphs in a doc and turns them into a bilingual table.
Basically emulates the 'Convert To Table' function in Word."""
    Par: Paragraph
    Tbl: Table
    for Par in Doc.paragraphs:
        # add a new table and move it to before the paragraph
        Tbl = Doc.add_table(1, 2)
        Par._p.addprevious(Tbl._element)
        LeftCell: _Cell = Tbl.cell(0, 0)
        RightCell: _Cell = Tbl.cell(0, 1)
        LeftPar: Paragraph = LeftCell.paragraphs[0]
        RightPar: Paragraph = RightCell.paragraphs[0]
        CopyParagraphFormatting(LeftPar, Par)
        CopyParagraphFormatting(RightPar, Par)
        # after copying formatting, copy all the content and hide as needed
        for Content in Par.iter_inner_content():
            if isinstance(Content, Run):
                LeftRun = LeftPar.add_run(Content.text)
                CopyRunFormatting(LeftRun, Content)
                RightRun = RightPar.add_run(Content.text)
                CopyRunFormatting(RightRun, Content)
                if SourceRight:
                    RightRun.font.hidden = True
                else:
                    LeftRun.font.hidden = True
            elif isinstance(Content, Hyperlink):
                LeftHpl: Hyperlink = AddHyperlink(
                    LeftPar, Content.address, Content.text
                )
                RightHpl: Hyperlink = AddHyperlink(
                    RightPar, Content.address, Content.text
                )
                if SourceRight:
                    for run in RightHpl.runs:
                        run.font.hidden = True
                else:
                    for run in LeftHpl.runs:
                        run.font.hidden = True
        # Remove the original paragraph and move on
        Par._p.getparent().remove(Par._element)
```

Problem here is that the `iter_inner_content()` function only iterates over runs and hyperlinks (and all the runs inside them). However, I sometimes get documents with Rich or Plain Text Content Control in them and these are unfortunately not picked up by this function and it either leaves a blank space if the Content Control was inside the paragraph or skips the paragraph all together if the whole Paragraph was a Content Control.

And that's where the question in the comes in, how can I also get the text from these content control, in document order, as this intended for translation, so keeping document order is extremely important here.

Keeping the Content Control intact is not required, if I can get a solution that would let me extract the text inside it and just turn into a regular text run in the table, that would be enough.

Thanks a lot for any help you could give me!

Comment: *"I sometimes get documents with Rich or Plain Text Content Control in them"* Can you upload a sample document somewhere, then we can try experimenting with it

Comment: Hi @HåkonHægland, sample files attached!

Comment: which module have you used ?

Comment: only python-docx. I use pathlib and argparse in other parts of the code but that's not relevant for this question